# Cant create Preference in PreferenceCategory

Tags: android, preferences, preferenceactivity

I'm trying to create in code preference category.
It works correctly. But if i try to add Preference to my category i get NullPointer Exception.

```
        Preference p1 = new Preference(getActivity());
        p1.setTitle("Edit name");

        PreferenceCategory prefcat = new PreferenceCategory(getActivity());
        prefcat.setTitle("title");
        prefcat.setSummary("summ");
        prefcat.addPreference(p1); // HERE I GET NULL POINTER
        ps.addPreference(prefcat);
```

ps - its preferencescreen object. 
Why? I try to debug it, Exception throws by onPrepareAddPreference method of PreferenceCategory. Hpw to fix it?

Comment: Try to reverse the order of the last two lines: 

`ps.addPreference(prefcat); prefcat.addPreference(p1);`

Comment: @shoerat, that worked, thank you! You should write it as an answer so I can upvote it!

Comment: @Anonsage, whoa after 9 months it was useful for at least two people! :)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to add a child (i.e., `p1`) to a parent (i.e., `prefcat`) which does not exist in the family (i.e., `Preference`) hierarchy yet.

First, add `prefcat` to Preference screen and then add `prefcat`'s children. That's, reverse the order of the last two lines:

```
ps.addPreference(prefcat);
prefcat.addPreference(p1);
```

Glad it helped! :)

Comment: perfect ! and sensible.